# Filter by date range

Tags: date, ember.js, filter

In Ember it is easy to filter an array where you are looking for matching values ( Only return name == "John) What I can't figure out is how to filter with a greater than or less than ( Return all objects whose startDate is before today

In my app I have a collection of deliverables. I want to divide these deliverables into three categories: Due within ten days, Past due, and then the rest.

I found the following example in another SO post, but can't figure out how to use it to accomplish my goal

```
filterComputed: function() {
  return this.get('content').filter(function(item, index, enumerable){
    return item.firstName == 'Luke';
  });
}.property('content.@each')
```

Comment: there are a bunch of options to choose from, go here: http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_filter there, you'll find 'filter', 'filterBy', 'gt'(greater), 'gte', and a lot more.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do:

```
this.get('content').filter(function(item){
    return item.get('someProperty') > someVar;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return an array of objects within your defined date range. Should work in Ember ^2.x.

```js
filterComputed: computed('content.@each', 'startDate', 'endDate', function() {
  return this.get('content').filter(function(item) {
    var contentDate = item.get('date'); // expecting item to have a date property  
    return contentDate > this.get('startDate') && bookingDate < this.get('endDate');
  });
})
```

With ES6 you could even do something like this:

```js
filterComputed: computed('content.@each', 'startDate', 'endDate', function() {
  return this.get('content').filter(item => item.get('date') > this.get('startDate') && item.get('date') < this.get('endDate'));
})
```

If you have a simpler requirement, `computed.filterBy()` might be right for you. https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_filterBy

Also helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter